# Are the tutorial orb-layouts always the same?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

The tutorial involves five, single-stage Dungeons, and I think at least the first two have a set layout to demonstrate basic concepts (e.g., combos, mass attacking, enemy attack countdowns, and healing/recovery). Do all five parts start with the same layout? And spawn the same new orbs (once orbs have been removed by being matched)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The initial layout may be the same, but the new orbs that spawn are random.

Tutorial Dungeons, part 1, second enemy, first run
[image: Second enemy (blue ball) and orbs-board layout, first run]

Tutorial Dungeons, part 1, second enemy, second run. Different orbs for the first three rows (new orbs spawned).
[image: Second enemy (blue ball) and orbs-board layout, second run]

Tutorial Dungeons, part 2, first enemy, first run, after healing
[image: Tutorial Dungeons, part 2, first enemy, first run, after healing]

Tutorial Dungeons, part 2, first enemy, second run, after healing. Different orbs at 4-2 and 4-3, in the column where hearts were matched and thus new orbs spawned.
[image: Tutorial Dungeons, part 2, first enemy, second run, after healing]

Tutorial Dungeons, part 3, battle 2/3, first run, after light mass attack
!
[Tutorial Dungeons, part 3, battle 2/3, first run, after light mass attack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THCzZ.png)

Tutorial Dungeons, part 3, battle 2/3, second run, after light mass attack. Different orbs in the first two rows, in the columns where light orbs hearts were matched and thus new orbs spawned.
[image: Tutorial Dungeons, part 3, battle 2/3, second run, after light mass attack]